# scale custom marker according to zoom level Google Maps

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to be able to scale my markers accordingly based upon the zoom level. I found this code to resize an image, but it keeps the icon static.

```
 func imageWithImage(image:UIImage, scaledToSize newSize:CGSize) -> UIImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0);
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

I implement it as such,

```
  marker.icon = self.imageWithImage(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icnMapmarker"), scaledToSize: CGSize(width: 60.0, height: 60.0))
```

I can't seem to find a way to resize a custom marker based on zoom in IOS. In javascript, it has to do with scaledToSize function, but I don't see the same documentation in IOS.

Comment: Hey, Did you find any solution of this ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to trigger icon scaling whenever the user zooms in/out.

First off, make sure your map view controller implements `GMSMapViewDelegate`.

Then you can implement the following delegate method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
    // ... 
}
```

This method is called whenever the map moves OR zoom level changes. Inside this function you can get the current zoom and base your icon size on that.

Also, you may want to run your image resize function as follows:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    marker.icon = self.imageWithImage(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icnMapmarker"), scaledToSize: CGSize(width: 60.0, height: 60.0))
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It kinda helps. I was looking for more of a magic bullet like javascript has. It sounds like a lot of experimentation. Another problem is that if you zoom out, the based changes because the size is bigger.